# Programmatically download email attachments to Desktop

Tags: python, r, email, gmail, email-attachments

I often receive by email a CSV file.  The sender is always the same and the attached CSV file in the email always has the same name.  I would like for this file to automatically be automatically downloaded to my Desktop.  This way each time I go to run my code on it, I don't have to manually open up my email and search for the email, download, it, etc.

I'd setup this attachment download program as a chron job so that it automatically scans through each morning.

Are there any resources for how to do this?  It's sent to a gmail account, if that matters.

I'd prefer this program to be in R, but I can also do Python!   Is this even possible?

Example:

```
       sender:   your_data@data_provider.com
       subject:  sometimes varies, but normally the same
       attachment:  data.csv   (always called this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get)

specifically, the [Users.messages.attachments: get function](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get)

You'll have to authenticate to your account and then write the code body to first get the message ID that contains the attachment you want to automatically download.